# How to lock a text box to a specific amount of characters

Tags: c#

I'm making a little password generator and I want it to lock the output text box to 10 characters, so that when the user clicks the password genenerate button it does not just continue with an endless line of randomly generated passwords.

How can I do this?

Comment: _So that when they click the password gen button_ why not write an algorithm to produce 10 random numbers?

Comment: please give more details. your question is unclear.or show the code you have tried so far.

Answer (score 0):

There's a control on the text box in Visual Studio.

If you click the button and they go into properties there should be something called "max length".  Set that to however long you want it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Substring()` function to cut the extra characters in your generated password.

For an instance

```
string GeneratedPassword = "1234567891345678";

textBox1.Text = GeneratedPassword.Substring(0,10);
```

Also the `textBox1.MaxLength = 10` will not give you the desired result. It will only limit input of the character manually in the textbox. It will not limit input of characters programmatically.